# Can't view my database on the browser while using Controller via Eloquent ORM (Laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-5, eloquent

Sorry if I was not able to word my question well..

I can't seem to get my database to show up after running my controller url  localhosts/8000/lists .. It doesn't give any error but rather executes the else statement of "No list found".. I have seeded by database using db:seed and tinker console. I went further to double check my database using phpmyadmin and MySQL CLI and my table is properly filled.

Below is my ListController.php

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\larmodel;

class ListsController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $lists = larmodel::all();
    return view('lists.index')->with('lists', $lists);

}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}
```

}

LarmodelTableSeeder.php below

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\larmodel;

class LarmodelTableSeeder extends Seeder {

public function run()
{

larmodel::create([
'name' => 'San Juan Vacation',
'description' => 'Things to do before we leave for Puerto Rico!'
]);

larmodel::create([
'name' => 'Home Winterization',
'description' => 'Winter is coming.'
]);

larmodel::create([
'name' => 'Rental Maintenance',
'description' => 'Cleanup and improvements for new tenants'
]);

}
}
```

My view- index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')

<h1>Lists</h1>
@if ($lists->count() > 0)
<ul>
    @foreach ($lists as $list)
    <li>{{ $list->name}}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
@else
<p>
  No lists found!
</p>
@endif

@endsection
```

My route.php

```
Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index'); 
Route::get('/loop', 'WelcomeController@loop');
Route::get('/sublime', 'WelcomeController@sublime');
Route::resource('/lists', 'ListsController');
```

I am new to php and laravel, I will be grateful if this is fixed.. From my deduction, it seems my model or controller is not communicating properly with the database.

To iterate: The output is "No list Found" , instead of it fetching the table elements of the database.

Thanks, in anticipation.

Comment: Please try in your index method of controller to use `dd(larmodel::all()->toJson());` before the return statement. What this does is gets all objects in larmodel, casts to json object and dumps it on the screen. please let us know what it shows.

Comment: Thanks gravy But it only showed an array braces [ ]

Comment: please try again, but replace `dd(larmodel::all()->toJson());` with `dd(\App::environment()); ` and check your config for that environment. Finally, if you could double check that you are seeding the correct database?

Comment: It outputted [local] ... Yes, I am seeding the right db..    My regret is that my model(class) is named larmodel while my database is larmodels. Next I will use very distinct name for both.. but I can't still see the db..

Comment: Happy to state that the problem was resolved just now. My instinct suggested I restart my system which I normally don't do. Thanks gravy for your suggestions. Appreciate